# Creating a rails form to build comments in a second part of the application (modal)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

New question at the bottom.

<s>Photos are shown at example.com/photos/:id 
User photos are paginated at example.com/users/2</s>

I want to create a form that can be displayed at example.com/users/2 to build comments. I can currently build comments at example.com/photos/:id. However, the instance variable at example.com/users/2 is different than example.com/photos/:id and will not work with `CommentsController > def create`

```
PhotosController

  def show
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  end

CommentsController

  def create
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:photo_id])
    @comment = @photo.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.save
    redirect_to photo_path(@photo)
  end   

UsersController 

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @photos = @user.photos.order('created_at desc').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 12)
  end
```

Each users photos are paginated in an instagram like way, displaying a thumb in rows that is clicked to display a modal.

```
Users > show.html.erb 

.
.
<% @photos.in_groups_of(3, false).each do |group| %>
  <% group.each do |photo| %>
    <a data-toggle="modal" href=<%="#"+"#{photo.id}"%>>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="thumb">
          <%= image_tag(photo.picture.thumb.url, class: "img-responsive") %>

.
.
.
```

<s><%= form_for([photo.id, photo.id.comments.build]) do |f| %></s>

```
   <%= f.label :content %><br>
   <%= f.text_area :content %>
   <%= f.submit %>

<% end %></s>
```

The form above does not work, Heroku error message:

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `comments' for 23:Fixnum):
```

23 is the :id of my last(first) photo.

Edit: This was answered below, to be changed to:

```
<%= form_for([photo, Comment.new]) do |f| %>

   <%= f.label :content %><br>
   <%= f.text_area :content %>
   <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

I also changed `CommentsController` from `redirect_to photo_path(@photo)` to `redirect_to :back` however this is closing my modal where the form is located. What code do I need after `@comment.save` to keep the modal open with the new comment visible?

Comment: Timmy, what's the question?

Comment: The form I am using does not work.

Comment: I think you should define "does not work" and add it to your question. But, that might just be me.

Comment: thx I updated it with the Heroku error message.

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss try this one: `<%= form_for([photo, Comment.new]) do |f| %>`

Comment: thanks this worked. i will accept it as the answer if you create an answer. my next problem is that after changing `redirect_to photo_path(@photo)` to `redirect_to :back` in the `CommentsController` it is closing the modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the form to

```
<%= form_for([photo, Comment.new]) do |f| %>
```